# Get related table's related record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables **ClaimHeader**, **ResClaim** and **ResActivity**. **ClaimHeader** table's primary key is used as foreign key in **ResClaim** table and **ResClaim** table's primary key is used as foreign key in **ResActivity** table.

Below is my tables

```
ClaimHeader:

HeaderID  FileID    FileName
1         fileid1    file1.xml
2         fileid2    file2.xml
3         fileid3    file3.xml
4         fileid4    file4.xml
--------------------------------------------------
ResClaim:

ClaimPKID  HeaderPKID    ClaimDateSettlement
1          1             2017-04-08
2          1             2017-03-08
3          2             2017-04-10
4          3             2017-05-08
--------------------------------------------------
ResActivity:

ActivityPKID  ClaimPKID    ActivityNet
1             1             400
2             2             3000
3             2             2030
4             3             5000
```

[Tables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6xrr.png)

**ResClaim** table uses **HeaderPKID** as the foreign key from **ClaimHeader** table and **ResActivity** table uses **ClaimPKID** as the foreign key from **ResClaim** table

My scenario is i should display related record from all the three tables.

For example i want to display **FileID** from **ClaimHeader** table , Total claims count from **ResClaim** table and Sum of **ActivityNet** from **ResActivity** table with the matching condtion.

My expected result would be:

```
FileID   |  Total Claim(s) |  ActivityNet 
--------------------------------------------------
fileid2  |    1            |   5030 (3000+2030)
--------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried below query:

```
SELECT 
  `ClaimHeader`.*, 
  count(ResClaim.ClaimPKID) as claims,  
  sum(ResActivity.ActivityNet) as net 
FROM 
  `ClaimHeader` 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN `ResClaim` 
    ON ResClaim.ClaimPKID = ClaimHeader.HeaderID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN `ResActivity` 
    ON ResClaim.ClaimPKID = ResActivity.ActivityPKID
```

The above query is not returning related record values - instead of that it's returning sum of all the columns and count from ResActivity and ResClaim table.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text...) And also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Have edited my question @jarlh

Comment: Great! Add the expected result as well.

Comment: you know about INNER JOINs, right?

Comment: Added my expected result @jarlh

Comment: Values please, for all result-set columns!

Comment: have added values @jarlh

Comment: Step 1: `JOIN` the tables!

Comment: The results don't make sense. Claim 1 is related to header 1, whose fileID is fileid1, not fileid2. An activity record with 5030 doesn't even exist in your sample data. Anyway, go and learn about SQL JOINs if you haven't already. Then the query (assuming you first decide on some meaningful expected output) is not very tricky. Try it. If you get stuck, post the code here. This is beginner stuff, there's no point us handing it on a plate to you if you don't understand the concepts involved.

Comment: Also in the question text you claim to want to report ClaimDateSettlement, but then your sample output data includes the Claim ID instead. It will help us - and you - to put some clarity and consistency into your expected result.

Comment: @ADyson.... Sorry for unclear explanation i have updated my question. The realated record has more than one so i just want total count from ResClaim table and sum of  ActivityNet from ResActivity table.

Comment: any particular reason you're using right outer join? an inner join ought to be fine. Also you probably need a GROUP BY clause so it'll group it by FileId (I assume). And selecting * isn't a good move in this case - you expected result says you want FileId so select exactly that

Comment: Your expected result shows one fileid (fileid2). So you just want to show that one? Why then is there no `WHERE` clause in your query? Or do you want to select more rows? One per fileid maybe? As to ClaimDateSettlement: I don't understand this either. You say you want to show it, but your expected result doesn't contain it. So what do you want to show? The number of claims as in your expected sample result? Or the number of different ClaimDateSettlement? Or something else still?

Comment: And the right outer joins don't make any sense. Do you want left ones? Can a ClaimHeader have no claims, so you want to show them with count zero? Can a claim have no activities, so you want to show a sum of zero?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner .. ClaimHeader table has many relationship with ResClaim Table and ResClaim table has many relationship with ResActivity table.. So i want to display ResClaim total count belongs to ClaimHeader and Activty Tables Net amont total for the particular Claim.

Comment: On a sidenote: Stay consistent with your names. If the table is called `claimheader` or `claim_header`, then you should call it's ID `claimheaderid`  or `claim_header_id` in this and any other table. With a column called `fileid` I'd expect another table named `file` you are referring to. But then, why have the `filename` in table `claim_header`? That should be in the `file` table. If there is no `file` table, then there should be no `fileid` in the claim header table.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not completely clear what you are asking. It seems you either want one result row per claim header or one result row per file. So group by the column in question.

By joining all records you get of course claim headers and claims multifold, e.g. with

- claim headers: head1, head2
- claims for head1: claim10, claim11
- claims for head2: claim20, claim21
- actions for claim 10: action100, action101
- actions for claim 11: action110, action111
- actions for claim 20: action200, action201

you get this intermediate result from the joins:

```
header | claim   | action
-------+---------+----------
head1  | claim10 | action100
head1  | claim10 | action101
head1  | claim11 | action110
head1  | claim11 | action111
head2  | claim20 | action200
...
```

Now by grouping per header, you get one aggregated result row for head1, one for head2. As the intermediate result contains one record per action, you can easily sum them. But as to claims: there are four records for head1, and if you do `count(*)` or `count(claimpkid)` you get a result of 4 (`count(claimpkid)` counts all `claimpkid` that are not null, which is always the case in this example). What you want to do instead is counting *distinct* claims (namly two here: claim10 and claim11). So use `COUNT DISTINCT`.

```
select 
  h.headerid, 
  count(distinct c.claimpkid) as claims,  
  coalesce(sum(a.activitynet), 0) as net 
from claimheader h
left outer join resclaim c on c.claimpkid = h.headerid 
left outer join resactivity a on a.activitypkid = c.claimpkid
group by h.headerid
order by h.headerid;
```

I am using left outer joins (and `COALESCE`) for the case that a header has no claims or a claim has no actions, for which we would show zeros rather then removing them from the results.

As mentioned, if you want this per file, then select `fileid` and group by it instead of `headerid`.